# Income or incomes?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Today I read in an article :

> ...when your incomes grow....

My question is, should it be incomes or income?

In first case suppose, I have a one source of income. In that case I can say:
when my income grows....

In second case suppose I have three sources of income. In that case what will it be...**incomes  grow or income grows ?**

To my understanding, no matter how many sources are there,income is a singe entity.

So, which one is correct? OR, can both be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly normal to talk about all of a person's sources of income as, collectively, their income. They might then talk about an individual source of income as "this income, that income", but it would be unusual to use *income* in the plural about the separate sources.

However, "your incomes" would be a normal phrasing where *you* is plural. If you were addressing several people collectively, such as a class of kids or a married couple, "your incomes" refers to each person's individual income, collectively.

(It would also be relatively normal to use the singular *income* for a married couple as well, though old-fashioned.)

Comment: Oh..well, *your* used as a plural...this makes sense. I haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple sources of income then you can say "My source**s** of incom**e** have grown." Saying `"My incomes grow"` or `"My incomes are growing"` sounds a little clunky.

Comment: *My sources of income have grown* - doesn't it mean that the number of sources has increased ? If yes, then I didn't mean that. I wanted to mean the amount has increased.

Comment: No, "sources of income have grown" wouldn't be taken to mean more sources, but bigger sources. "Grown" indicates a single entity getting bigger, and the plural indicates that each of them have grown.